# Read values for a specific key from the entire JSON body in Java

Tags: java, json

My JSON response body looks like this:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "responseData": {
        "category": "Seeds",
        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Seeds.jpg",
        "display": "Seeds",
        "children": [
            {
                "category": "Vegetables",
                "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Vegetables.jpg",
                "display": "Vegetables",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "category": "Cabbage",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Cabbage.jpg",
                        "display": "Cabbage",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "06523d5d-c2c4-4f83-a94b-8209173f05c8"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Cowpea (Chauli)",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Cowpea (Chauli).jpg",
                        "display": "Cowpea (Chauli)",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "f9ccc378-58d7-49b5-a3e2-7639ca967b86"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Hot Pepper (Chilli)",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Hot Pepper (Chilli).jpg",
                        "display": "Hot Pepper (Chilli)",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "4226ebc8-4932-48c2-a2c1-0e52bbd852a9"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Cauliflower",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Cauliflower.jpg",
                        "display": "Cauliflower",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "759fac6c-a3fa-42d0-8b15-20797c827c67"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Bottle Gourd (Dudhi)",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Bottle Gourd (Dudhi).jpg",
                        "display": "Bottle Gourd (Dudhi)",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "6719800f-edbc-4fe3-8ae1-e537f6943693"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Cucumber",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Cucumber.jpg",
                        "display": "Cucumber",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "310a650a-52b8-4090-9b43-9d1b0b4dbdd1"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Ginger",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Ginger.jpg",
                        "display": "Ginger",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "bd2f9443-5b04-4609-95de-2ae69da053bd"
                    }
                ],
                "id": "488fafe3-5940-4eef-b7d5-3361a3855a0d"
            },
            {
                "category": "Pulses",
                "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Pulses.jpg",
                "display": "Pulses",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "category": "Urid Bean (Urad)",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Urid Bean (Urad).jpg",
                        "display": "Urid Bean (Urad)",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "5a38dbef-2118-4cbc-b596-ed2ab58b18cb"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Pigeon Pea(Tur)",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Pigeon Pea(Tur).jpg",
                        "display": "Pigeon Pea (Tur)",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "040e2713-05ab-43e4-b09b-d19f52f96f15"
                    }
                ],
                "id": "b9526fc2-db2b-485e-a2ce-c2068684d66d"
            },
            {
                "category": "Cash Crop",
                "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Cash Crop.jpg",
                "display": "Cash Crop",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "category": "Gum Guar",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Gum Guar.jpg",
                        "display": "Gum Guar",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "1e7ccb01-274a-40bb-8446-379ea8870047"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Cotton",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Cotton.jpg",
                        "display": "Cotton",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "7764aaba-ae3c-470e-a20b-55d6ce8ae095"
                    }
                ],
                "id": "9636b237-7bc0-40f8-9dec-d6d6c442e293"
            },
            {
                "category": "Cereals",
                "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Cereals.jpg",
                "display": "Cereals",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "category": "Pearl Millet (Bajara)",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Pearl Millet (Bajara).jpg",
                        "display": "Pearl Millet (Bajara)",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "4c0a7b9f-1dc8-4eed-914b-2dcfea568caa"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Maize",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Maize.jpg",
                        "display": "Maize",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "812c864d-2491-4ce9-bb75-72bb1da1fc53"
                    }
                ],
                "id": "693a3515-8c2d-4d7c-9071-ce4dd400ae27"
            },
            {
                "category": "Oil Seeds",
                "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Oil Seeds.jpg",
                "display": "Oil Seeds",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "category": "Sesame (Tal)",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Sesame (Tal).jpg",
                        "display": "Sesame",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "21eaacf9-7dd4-4890-9e11-985b2dc6eb52"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Castor",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Castor.jpg",
                        "display": "Castor",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "c4118dea-4ccb-499c-817e-2e8a6b59c6a4"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Groundnut",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Groundnut.jpg",
                        "display": "Groundnut",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "e8227101-3a80-468b-84fc-fc9758440b2d"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Mustard",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Mustard.jpg",
                        "display": "Mustard",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "bf087d9c-46fc-4317-8915-5c29c9d4be43"
                    }
                ],
                "id": "8bf12226-353d-4227-aa0d-19f02f8ea76c"
            },
            {
                "category": "Fruits",
                "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Fruits.jpg",
                "display": "Fruits",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "category": "Papaya",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Papaya.jpg",
                        "display": "Papaya",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "de8e5fdc-cc01-44be-ba94-679fe98fd370"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Watermelon",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Watermelon.jpg",
                        "display": "Watermelon",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "466aeb9e-baf1-48a8-82ab-eaaa5e2d12ec"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Mango",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Mango.jpg",
                        "display": "Mango",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "0e1f7681-9cc2-4efa-b726-2102438eec88"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Muskmelon",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Muskmelon.jpg",
                        "display": "Muskmelon",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "3b7156ef-5158-4a90-ae1a-4a02688cc4b3"
                    }
                ],
                "id": "6a8c7f46-277a-4ebf-97ad-6d6ab2554ff2"
            },
            {
                "category": "Spices",
                "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Spices.jpg",
                "display": "Spices",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "category": "Fennel",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Fennel.jpg",
                        "display": "Fennel",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "cc8940d3-ca03-4ccc-ba53-4fbf62d560ea"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Cumin",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Cumin.jpg",
                        "display": "Cumin",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "432a3fa6-d3ab-4c44-a119-9a6f396a64fd"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Fenugreek",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Fenugreek.jpg",
                        "display": "Fenugreek",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "862ea254-95e3-48e4-ac77-7937f91f9a60"
                    }
                ],
                "id": "d4ee8a4e-a983-4f8b-b6d9-5a10a87bfba5"
            },
            {
                "category": "Flowers",
                "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Flowers.jpg",
                "display": "Flowers",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "category": "Tuberose",
                        "image": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Tuberose.jpg",
                        "display": "Tuberose",
                        "children": [],
                        "id": "4af24831-9f91-4065-8b33-5af13a310f04"
                    }
                ],
                "id": "70a34981-b6d9-4f6d-8d85-b2680297867a"
            }
        ],
        "id": "5241bf95-38b4-4b66-a4e0-a073a5bf7bc2"
    },
    "message": ""
}
```

I would like to read all the values for the key **"image"** from the entire response body in an ArrayList.

Tried below code to achieve this:

```
String yourJson = res.asString();
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement element = parser.parse(yourJson);
JsonObject obj = element.getAsJsonObject();
Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries = obj.entrySet();
for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry: entries) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey()); //prints keys
    System.out.println(entry.getValue()); //prints values
}
```

I've done good amount of search for finding a solution, but I haven't been able to find an elegant and reusable solution for this problem. I'm open to use any library for this. Please suggest.

Comment: I guess this is for java, if so web is full of examples

Comment: Dude , you want us to send a java code and spoon feed you ? Dude at least tell us what solutions did you try so that we can precisely understand and  help you. Come back with solutions you tried and then we can help you. Meanwhile try [this](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.json%22%20AND%20a%3A%22json%22)

Comment: @AsifAli Thanks for your response. I tried the code as updated in my question, but it gives my only `status`, `responseData` and `message` keys.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Yes, as the topic heading says, it is needed for Java. I haven't been able to a solution which would work recursively on my entire JSON response body.

Comment: is it all image keys url values you want to fetch, or is specific image keys?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ All image keys URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OP requested to extract all values of image keys.

This can be achieved many ways, a simple classical way using just regular java, I have built a method that can take a JSON String and key. It will return you a list of ArrayList of urls strings:

```
public static List<String> extract(String json, String key) {

    List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] content = json.split(",");

    String keyStr = "\"" + key + "\":";

    for (String s : content) {
        if (s.trim().startsWith(keyStr))
            urls.add(s.trim().replace("\"", "").substring(7));
    }

    return urls;
}
```

And you will the output is shown down in the answer.

Another way, I have found very interesting and helpful [post](http://crunchify.com/in-java-how-to-flatten-or-unflatten-complex-json-objects-into-flat-map-like-structure/) covering a general way to flat & map JSON objects. Btw this is more for Java8.

So my solution is based on the mentioned post.

First of all import json flattener jar (com.github.wnameless), I have used Maven to import it.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.wnameless</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-flattener</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Secondly I have built a method that takes your JSON content and the key you want to extract, and it will return you all Urls as list.

```
public static List<String> extract(String json, String key) {

    List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        Map<String, Object> flattenedJsonMap =
                JsonFlattener.flattenAsMap(jsonObject.toString());
        flattenedJsonMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
                    if (k.contains(key)) {
                        urls.add(v.toString());
                    }
                }
        );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return urls;

}
```

in your main method just call

```
List<String> urls = extract(res, "image");
```

and you can test it either java8

```
urls.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or regular java way

```
for (String url : urls) {
    System.out.println(url);
}
```

And here is you got a list of all urls:

```
https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Seeds.jpg
https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Vegetables.jpg
https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Cabbage.jpg
https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/agrostarcatalog/static/Cowpea (Chauli).jpg
......etc.
```

> Note: you can also use it to extract values of other keys, it is also possible to parse JSON file, but that require a bit code modification.

Link to:

- https://github.com/wnameless/json-flattener
- http://crunchify.com/in-java-how-to-flatten-or-unflatten-complex-json-objects-into-flat-map-like-structure/

Comment: I'm trying to write multiple extract() methods to handle different data types, but the logic in extract() method (specifically the code `flattenedJsonMap.forEach((k, v)`) works well for String and Boolean types, but not for Integer. I get compile time error "The method add(Integer) in the type List<integer> is not applicable for the arguments (object)" for the line `urls.add(v);`

Comment: The easiest way when you print the results just use this Integer.valueOf(url) if you any way want to change your data type then urls.add(Integer.valueOf(v))

Comment: That does not seem to be working either, so I'm using the `extract()` method that returns a `List` of `Strings` even for handling `Integer` cases for now. Thanks anyway!